# Read a csv file, then sort it, then rewrite it

Tags: python

I want to read in a csv file, sort it, then rewrite a new file. Any help?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: there is a csv module for doing the reading and writing

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at the python documentation of the `csv` module:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

You could also use pandas, but that might be overkill if you're new to python.

#### To give you some initial code to play with:

```
# file test.csv
2,a,x
0,b,y
1,c,z
```

Code:

```
import csv

csv_lines = []

# read csv
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        csv_lines.append(row)

# sort by first column
csv_lines_sorted = sorted(csv_lines, key=lambda x: x[0])

# write csv
with open('test_sorted.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in csv_lines_sorted:
        writer.writerow(row)
```